# What is the advantage of has sperate front-end page for mobile and desktop?

Tags: responsive, mobile-devices, front-end-optimization

When we access to facebook page on mobile, it redirect to URL 'm.facebook.com' that m represent for mobile. Even when we access to this URL in desktop, it still return mobile UI.

As I guessed, this was for reduce CSS or JS or anythings that handle differencely display for mobile and desktop.

But I wonder there is other advantage for that? What is the keyword for this kind of technical? This must be archived by perform some actions in both back-end and front-end side. I did a lot of search but still not found any artical about this technical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did more search and with correct key word, it done. For anyone need the answer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Mobile/Separate_sites

Answer (score 0):

If it is a small business with a minimal amount of content & pages responsive design would serve the purpose. But if the business is having a large portal loaded with lots of content, services & features then it is worth going for a separate website for the mobile version.

1. Responsive designs mostly support all major screen sizes. But while
   handling large content it could be tricky and it will need a good
   amount of planning during the designing phase.
2. A responsive website usually takes more loading time than a separate mobile website.
3. It saves efforts while maintaining the website.

So if it is a large business then a separate website would be a better choice.